# Returning an immutable map containing a single modified entry from another one

Tags: scala

I have an immutable map from which I wish to change a single element and then return another immutable map.  Am I stuck with copying all elements twice?

```
  val inmap = Map('a'->1,'b'->2)
  import collection.mutable
  val mmap = mutable.Map(inmap.toList:_*)
  mmap('b')= 3
  val mmap2 = Map(mmap.toList:_*)

  mmap2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(b -> 3, a -> 1)
```

Just wondering if that were the 'required' price for immutability on the 'frontiers' of our methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the updated method:

```
scala> val inmap = Map('a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2)
inmap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> val updated = inmap.updated('b', 3)
updated: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 3)
```

[API doc for Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map): look to the updated method.

Comment: you got it backwards:  char -> Int -  not vice versa !

Comment: dude i was playing there - no need to have switched it back.